# Javascript Date Object's getUTC and setUTC

Tags: javascript, jquery, utc

I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around the javascript object's getUTC and setUTC methods.

I'm working on a frontend countdown clock to next shipping cuttoff using a jQuery plugin, TinyTimer. I cannot use any backend scripts on the platform I'm working on. The timer is working well, except I don't know how to adjust for time zone

```
var d = new Date();
/* Get Month & Time & Day of the week*/
var monthOfTheYear = d.getMonth();
var dayOfTheMonth = d.getDate();
var dayOfTheWeek = d.getDay();
/*New Years Day */
if( monthOfTheYear == 0 && dayOfTheMonth == 1){
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
$('#timer').prepend("<p>Closed today for New Year's Day</p>");
}
/*Memorial Day */
if( monthOfTheYear == 4 && dayOfTheMonth >= 25 &&  dayOfTheWeek == 1){
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
$('#timer').prepend("<p>Closed today for Memorial Day</p>");
}
/*Independence Day */ 
if( monthOfTheYear == 6 && dayOfTheMonth == 4 ){
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
$('#timer').prepend("<p>Closed today for Independence Day</p>");
}
/*Labor Day */
if( monthOfTheYear == 8 && dayOfTheMonth <= 7 && dayOfTheWeek == 1){
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
$('#timer').prepend("<p>Closed today for Labor Day</p>");
}
/*Thanksgiving */
if( monthOfTheYear == 10 && dayOfTheMonth <= 28 && dayOfTheMonth >= 22 && dayOfTheWeek == 4){
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
$('#timer').prepend("<p>Closed today for Thanksgiving.</p>");
}
 /*Day after Thanksgiving */
if( monthOfTheYear == 10 && dayOfTheMonth <= 29 && dayOfTheMonth >= 23 && dayOfTheWeek == 5){
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
$('#timer').prepend("<p>Courier closed today for day after Thanksgiving.</p>");
}
/*Christmas */
if( monthOfTheYear == 11 && dayOfTheMonth == 25){
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
$('#timer').prepend("<p>Closed today for Christmas's Day!</p>");
}   
/*New Year's Eve */
if( monthOfTheYear == 11 && dayOfTheMonth == 31){
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
$('#timer').prepend("<p>Closed today for New Year's Eve!</p>");
}   
/* Check that it is not a saturday or sunday*/
if( dayOfTheWeek == 0){
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
}else if( dayOfTheWeek === 6 ){
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2);
}
/* Set the time to 4:30pm */
d.setHours(16);
d.setMinutes(30);
d.setSeconds(0);
/* Initialize TinyTimer */
$('#timer').tinyTimer({ to: d });
```

Comment: I don't understand what `getUTC*()` methods have to do with your code. In fact, I don't understand why you think you need to "adjust for local time zone" at all, since most of the `Date` methods assume local time zone.

Comment: but why js clock. if user change time what will happen ?  i like this one http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/servertime.shtml

Comment: You need to describe what the input is, what you expect the outcome to be and what it actually is. What time zone adjustment do you think you need to make?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't very clear. The purpose of the clock is to tell the user how long they have to place their order before our shipping cuttoff time. If they place the order before that time, the order gets shipped the same day. It is supposed to run out at 4:30pm Pacific Standard Time weekdays, except holidays.